# What happens if I retreat first?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Often Rebels will try to power up their FTL drives and jump away to report my position. What happens if I manage to stall them long enough to get my own drives online and jump away first.
Do they count as having gotten away and warning the rebels (causing them to catch up faster?) Or is it as effective as destroying them?

Bonus: Same situation, but before I leave or they power up their drives, they offer to surrender? If I accept their surrender, will the report me?

Comment: Great question, I'm sad I have only one upvote to give.

Comment: Bonus: No, they wont. If they surrender, you kind of have won the fight.

Comment: @ChaosPointDK Are you sure about that? I wouldn't put it past them to have thought of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Rebel fleet gets faster if you run away from a Rebel. And if you accept surrender they normally don't report you. I think it's a 50% chance that they will report you.

Comment: Can you back that up somehow?

Comment: Although I'd also like to see a citation, this does make sense to me. I've noticed a speed difference in how fast the Rebels arrive, several times now, but didn't think that it might have been an escaping Rebel that did it. (And that's the *last* time I accept their surrender. :)